# Could not start a new session. Response code 500

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, selenide

Please help me.I use WebDriverManager for configuration drivers.

```
  Configuration.browser = "edge";
        WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
```

but when run tests I have next error:
Step failed
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of Microsoft Edge WebDriver only supports Microsoft Edge version 125
Current browser version is 123.0.2420.53
How I can fix this error?

Comment: You need to install the webdriver binary that matches the browser version that you are using.  Or upgrade your browser to version 125.

Comment: Alternatively modify your selenium code to use webdriver manager and that will automatically download and set up the version of the webdriver binary to match your browser's current version; see https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Microsoft Edge WebDriver that matches the Edge browser version that you are using (123.0.2420.53). You can click this link: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/?form=MA13LH to Download WebDriver. Please note that the stable latest version of Edge has been updated to 123.0.2420.65. [image]

Surely, you can also refer to Stephen's suggestion: modify your selenium code to use WebDriver manager to match your browser's current version.